# Is it possible to connect LiPo level indicators in parallel?

Tags: batteries, lipo

I've never studied the terminology of electrics so I had a hard time searching for whatever I'm asking. If this is a duplicate please mark it as such :)

I've got four battery packs in series to produce a higher voltage output, it all works great. I also have four individual battery level indicators, however these are connected separately over each battery like so:

[image]

However, from what little I know it should be possible to connected them more according to this picture:

[image]

I'm thinking it might give the wrong readings if one cell is higher than lowest one?

The indicators are one of these classic alarm ones:

[image]

Again, I'm sorry if the descriptions are off or the terminology isn't there.. This isn't my main field and I'm a home brew enthusiast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: That is a definite **NO**

Your LiPo cells are in series. The orange and purple connections in your second drawing are **the same** as the connections directly above them where you switch the LiPos in series.

So there is a straight path: from purple wire down, purple wire up to the right, up to the battery contact hopping over to the battery where we started from. That's a **DEAD SHORT**.

You might have drawn the connections above and below the battery as separate connections **but they're not**.

I have drawn two of these shorting paths.

[image]

It will ruin your day ! So don't !

Comment: Great answer, the image is a perfect touch for someone like me! Thanks for saving my day!